# Archive block giving SQLSTATE[42000] error

Tags: views, blocks

I'm trying to make a view archive block to filter my posts by year and month etc. I'm following http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-create-monthly-archive-block-drupal-blog-views, but I keep getting an SQL error.

See below my error and the running query also. Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

> [image: the error]

> [image: Query]